# How to add exclude certain packages from an external maven dependency

Tags: java, security, maven, exception, tomcat

My Application depends on an external jar

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.objectweb.joram</groupId>
    <artifactId>jftp</artifactId>
    <version>1.52</version>
  </dependency>
```

I am mainly interested in using the following package **import net.sf.jftp.net.***

But looks like this jar also exposes certain classes in org.apache.log4j package, causing the following exception on deploying application war file to tomcat

**java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package**

Is there any way i can avoid error?

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html Does this help at all?

Comment: Thanks for link, i have already browsed the page. but, how can i determine group id and artifact id for exclusion from the jar file?.

Answer (score 1):

First you can use

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

to see exactly which dependencies are loaded by jftp. Then, exclude the ones you don't want like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.objectweb.joram</groupId>
  <artifactId>jftp</artifactId>
  <version>1.52</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
      <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: Tried this with no luck :(                                                                                                    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.objectweb.joram</groupId>
        <artifactId>jftp</artifactId>
        <version>1.52</version>
        <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-logging-api</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>